# base href repeated in url for angular 7 application

Tags: angular, angular7

I have created a hybrid application which runs Angular 7 and AngularJS code together. I have create a build using ng build and hosted that folder in IIS as an application under default web site as a myapp and I have given  `<base href="/myapp/">` in index.html. It is single page application without any routing. My left side panel contains list of programs and on click of program, program details are loaded on right side panel. So my url for the application looks like this: `http://localhost/myapp/?pid=6133&view=overview`. The problem is when ever I click on program it is adding myapp in url. So when second time I click on program my url will be like `http://localhost/myapp/myapp/?pid=6133&view=overview`. It keeps on adding myapp.

Can you please let me know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

the first 'myapp' is the application context added by IIS and the second 'myapp' is the base href that you have provided in the index.html.

```
http://localhost/myapp/myapp/?pid=6133&view=overview
```

I had the same problem. So, the solution I followed is to use the HashLocationStrategy

```
{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
```

and build the application for production

```
ng build --prod --base-href=/myapp/
```

By providing the base path I ensured the styles and other files are loaded correctly as I was getting 404 error for styles and runtime.js, etc files.

By using HashLocationStrategy, I resolved 404 errors on refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with HashLocationStrategy is that every character after '#' is not send to a server.
It can cause a lot of trouble.
See [explanation](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/routing-strategies/#_hashlocationstrategy).